# Create list of objects parameter in cloudformation and pass it to a resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

I'm writing a cloud formation template to create an EMR cluster. Below is the sample code.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Description: Cloudformation Template to spin up EMR clusters

Parameters:

  EMRApplications:

    Description: 'MapReduce applications to be installed on this cluster (ex: Hadoop, Livy etc)'

    Type: CommaDelimitedList

Resources:

  EMRCluster:

    Type: AWS::EMR::Cluster

    Properties:

      Applications: !Ref EMRApplications
```

And I'm getting an error like:

```
Value of property Applications must be a list of objects
```

Is there a way to overcome this instead of statically defining the applications in the template?

Best,
Sarat

Comment: While creating the stack, I'm giving "Ganglia,Livy,Hadoop,Spark" as the parameter value (including quotes)

Answer (score 0):

The value of property "Applications" must be a list of objects which are of type "Application".

```
Applications:
  - AdditionalInfo: 
      Key: Value
    Args: 
      - String
    Name: Ganglia
    Version: String
 - AdditionalInfo: 
      Key: Value
   Args: 
      - String
   Name: Hadoop
   Version: String
```

Please see [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticmapreduce-cluster.html#cfn-elasticmapreduce-cluster-applications) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticmapreduce-cluster-application.html) in the documentation.

If you want to dynamically provide application names via parameters when creating the stack, you can define the parameter `EMRApplications` with type `List<String>`. When creating the stack, the parameter value would be "Hadoop,Ganglia,.." and they can be invoked as below in the template resource.

```
Applications:
  - Name: !Select [ 0,!Ref EMRApplications ]
    ...
  - Name: !Select [ 1 ,!Ref EMRApplications ]
    ...
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Swathi! In some cases, I may need different number of apps(2, 3, or 4 etc). Then we need to add them in the EMR resource manually. Firstly, do we have the type List<String>? Also, I want to go with instance fleet or group based on a parameter. I created a condition and when added the condition under TaskInstanceFleets > InstanceTypeConfigs , it's saying unsupported. How can I achieve this? Any suggestion?